# Run Atom editor as root in FileZilla for view/edit files

Tags: linux, editing, atom-editor, ftp-client, filezilla

I know how to open/edit files from the server in FileZilla. I set up this:

```
/usr/bin/atom
```

in `edit -> settings -> file editing`

But the problem is that it opens the file in non-root Atom mode.

How to open file in Atom editor as root?

Comment: So you want to open a file from a server and edit it with Atom, but you can't edit it since you need root privileges?

Answer (score 3):

Follow this step to edit the file in atom of file zilla

Edit -> Settings -> File editing

Refer the below image

[image]

This is actually worked for me after configuring this setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Atom. It has to do with the file-permissions on the server.

Even if you'd be able to start Atom as root you'll still not be able to view/edit files on the server. You have to change the permissions on the server-files.

Running a programm locally as root does not affect your permissions on a remote system.

Answer (score 0):

From top menu Select

```
Edit -> settings -> File editing
```

[image]

After changing the settings, If the changes not reflected for some reason restart FileZilla or select Reopen local file as below

[image]